# What is a cost effective substitute for Shea butter to be used in DIY natural deodorant?

Tags: personal-care, gardening, chemicals

I hope this is the correct SE site for this question.  I think most people like me are interested in avoiding putting chemicals under our arms that can put our health at risk.  I found [this recipe](https://www.treehugger.com/organic-beauty/recipe-homemade-deodorant-really-works.html) for DIY natural deodorant. The author of the article claims it works very well even after her cross fit workout.

Like you all, cost is also an important consideration for me.  Shea butter is imported from Ghana Africa.  After some searching I saw that avocado butter can be used in its place but that was for making soap.

Ideally the most cost-effective recipe would have all its ingredients sourcable from my back yard garden so a trip to the store would not be needed.  I live in New Jersey USA.

Answer (score 1):

There are few viable oil crops found in home gardens; fewer still that produce a fat that remains solid at room temperature without processing (hydrogenation).  One optional replacement for Shea butter might be cocoa butter, but I don't think this is a viable option for New Jersey gardens, since the cacao tree from which it is derived is native to Yucatan.

Another option would be a mixture of natural vegetable oil (olive oil is an option, and at least possible for your climate) and beeswax (people keep bees much further north than New Jersey).  The proportions can be varied to give the desired consistency, and olive oil doesn't (in my experience) tend to become rancid if it's kept in a sealed container.